# How to calculate Cronbach's alpha for reverse scored items?

Tags: r, alpha

I'm looking to calculate Cronbach's alpha for a 10-item scale (response: 0= Disagree to 3 = Agree), with items 2, 4, 8, 9 and 10 reversed scored.
I have tried to following code:
`cronbach(dataset, keys = c(1,-1, 1,-1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1,-1))`
however I keep getting the error message "unused argument".

I'm new to R and would appreciate any help!
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Where does the function `cronbach` come from? Please start R scripts with calls to `library()` in order to load the external packages you're using. Can you post code and sample data? Please edit **the question** with the code you ran and the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (`df` is the name of your dataset.)

Comment: The sample data should be rating scales usually likert. Imagine ordinal data from say 1 to 5 in as many columns as the length of the key vector.

Answer (score 0):

You need the package psych

```
install.packages("psych")
psych::alpha(dataset,keys=c(1,-1,1,-1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1)),na.rm=TRUE,
   check.keys=TRUE,n.iter=1,use="pairwise",warnings=TRUE)
```

Provided you know how to interpret the output and the warnings this will also work

```
psych::alpha(dataset,keys=NULL,na.rm=TRUE,
   check.keys=TRUE,n.iter=1,use="pairwise",warnings=TRUE)
```

You may also reverse using the psych::reverse function and then do a crombach alpha without having to input any more keys.

Comment: adding a verbal explanation can be very helpful

Comment: I agree with that